# New cup and cap symbol

Tags: symbols

I'm redrawing these symbols (don't ask why :)) How can I draw them more properly?
[image]

(Circle and line segments do not exactly intersect)

**My Code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mycupsymbol}{     
\hspace{1.1mm}\tikz[baseline, line width=0.6 pt, line cap=round]{
  \draw (1.103,0.08) -- ++(0,0.15);
  \draw (0.903,0.08) -- ++(0,0.15);
  \draw (1.103,0.08) arc (0:-180:0.1);
}
\hspace{1.1mm}}
\newcommand{\mycup}{\mycupsymbol}

\newcommand{\mycapsymbol}{     
\hspace{1.1mm}\tikz[baseline, line width=0.6 pt, line cap=round]{
  \draw[line width=0.581] (1.1033,-0.022) -- ++(0,0.15);
  \draw[line width=0.581] (0.9033,-0.022) -- ++(0,0.15);
  \draw (1.103,0.13) arc (0:180:0.1);
}
\hspace{1.1mm}}
\newcommand{\mycap}{\mycapsymbol}


\begin{document}

$$A_2\mycup \mycap S_2$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `amsmath`.  (The usage example doesn't even use `\[ ... \]`.)  A more appropriate tag might be `symbols`.

Comment: I know you told us not to ask why, but, well, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

1. It's better to use scalable units w.r.t. the font (`ex` as in my example, or `em`).
2. Draw all the paths with only one `\draw`, it's easier this way.
3. Create only one macro (`\mysymbol` in my case) with a parameter and rotate it.
4. Define before the macro variables with all the dimensions involved. This way it's easy to modify until you have exactly what you need.

That said, this is my example, **edited** as suggested by egreg in the comments. Previously there could be conflicts with the names of the macros. I also changed `\def` for `\newcommand` to make this macros.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\myheight{1.5ex} % cup and cap height
\newcommand\mywidth {1.2ex} % cup and cap width
\newcommand\mylinew {0.1ex} % cup and cap line width
\newcommand\spaceba {0.4ex} % space before and after
\newcommand{\mysymbol}[1]
{
  \hspace{\spaceba}
  \tikz[line width=\mylinew,line cap=round,rotate=#1]
    \draw (0,\myheight) -- (0,0.5*\mywidth) arc (-180:0:0.5*\mywidth) -- (\mywidth,\myheight);
  \hspace{\spaceba}
}
\newcommand{\mycup}{\mysymbol{0}}
\newcommand{\mycap}{\mysymbol{180}}

\begin{document}
\[A_2\mycup \mycap S_2\]
\huge
\[A_2\mycup \mycap S_2\]
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: How can I get the arc a little lower? @JuanCastaño

Comment: @cufcuf, you need to change the `baseline` but in that case there are some changes needed in the path too. Something like this: `\tikz[line width=\lw,line cap=round,rotate=#1,baseline=-0.4ex]
  {\draw (-0.5*\w,0.5*\h) -- (-0.5*\w,0.5*\w-0.5*\h) arc (-180:0:0.5*\w) -- (0.5*\w,0.5*\h);}`

Comment: Thank you @JuanCastaño

Comment: Using `\def` is not recommended. And in fact users of your code run into errors, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/615996/4427. Please, replace `\h`, `\w`, `\lw` and `\sp` with other names less likely to conflict with someone else's code.

Comment: @egreg, it's now edited, thanks for pointing it!!!