# A problem typing (') in LaTeX

Tags: superscripts, mathastext

What is this? I'm just trying to write `'`

Entry:

[image]

Output:

[image]

**My code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots,relsize}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\def\h {1.3ex} % cup and cap height
\def\w {1.2ex} % cup and cap width
\def\lw{0.12ex} % cup and cap line width
\def\sp{0.7269ex} % space before and after
\newcommand{\mysymbol}[1]
{
  \hspace{\sp}
  \tikz[line width=\lw,line cap=round,rotate=#1,baseline=-0.4ex]   {\draw (-0.5*\w,0.5*\h) -- (-0.5*\w,0.5*\w-0.5*\h) arc (-180:0:0.5*\w) -- (0.5*\w,0.5*\h);}
  \hspace{\sp}
}
\newcommand{\mycup}{\mysymbol{0}}
\newcommand{\mycap}{\mysymbol{180}}
\newcommand{\mysub}{\mysymbol{270}}
\newcommand{\mysup}{\mysymbol{-360}}

\begin{document}

        \begin{align*}
        p' \wedge q
        \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give a bit of context, i.e., the code of the document that shows this behavior? It is definitely not normal, `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\wedge(q' \wedge r)$
\end{document}` compiles without problems.

Comment: Please show the couple of lines of code -- preferably the code itself, not a screen shot of code -- that precede the one you've chosen to show.

Comment: I edited the code

Comment: It seems like the issue is with `\def\sp{0.7269ex}` and `\usepackage{mathastext}`, commenting either of these out fixes it. Also changing `\sp` to some other name, such as `\spp` fixes it.

Comment: Thank you @Willoughby I did the last thing you said and problem is solved.

Comment: Don't ever redefine `\sp` -- or, for that matter, `\sb` -- *unless* you want to come to grief. (Hint: `\sp` and `\sp` are short for superscript and subscript.)

Comment: Basically the problem is using `\def` (which is not LaTeX) - using `\newcommand`would have triggered a redefinition error. It's a good habit to use it especially for short macro names, where clashes are more probable.

Comment: You've already received an answer, but here's a good tip* for troubleshooting: look at what is bring printed and compare it with your preamble definitions. "0.7269ex" is a slightly random thing to be bring printed. You should then check your definitions---which, as others have said, should use `\newcommand` not `\def`---to see if this appears anywhere. This method doesn't find the culprit every time, and it certainly doesn't give the full answer given below, but it can help diagnose the issue. [*_I_ feel that it's a good tip; it works well for me, at least!]

Comment: To add to Mico's comment, don't use one or two letter macro names.  They're generally already being used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is occurs with the package `mathastext` and your definition of `\sp`.
It seems like `mathastext` uses `\sp` in its definition of `'`:

```
\def\mst@active@math@prime{\sp\bgroup\mskip\mst@prime@muskip\prim@s}
```

(taken from [here](https://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathastext/mathastext.pdf), page 55, line 215).
You can fix the problem by calling the macro something else.